# Asus P5BW-LA doesn't support PCIe graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, pci-express, pci

I've been continuing my escapades with my 11-year-old HP a1640n pre-built which uses an Asus P5BW-LA motherboard ("Buckeye" variant which has Intel integrated graphics) running Windows XP Pro SP3. I recently updated the motherboard BIOS from 3.08 to 3.17 and I noticed that the "PCIe" option under "Primary Video Adapter" disappeared (now I just have the options Onboard and PCI). I have been trying to get this graphics card to work with it:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00O6MPZNK/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_F4JOzbY2J2ABY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O6MPZNK)

However, whenever the card is installed in the PCIe x16 slot, there's no video signal or sounds playing whatsoever. Not even the BIOS screen. I took the card to a local computer repair shop and they were able to get a signal with it when it was installed in one of their machines, so the problem wasn't that the card was broken. I also tested out the DVI-D to VGA cable at work and it worked fine, so that wasn't the problem either.

Is my motherboard completely incapable of running a PCIe graphics card, or is it just incompatible with this one card for whatever reason? Is there a BIOS for this particular board newer than 3.17? I've seen a 5.08 BIOS, but that appears to be intended only for one of the "Basswood" (no onboard graphics) variants of the P5BW-LA.

Comment: Sounds like you should roll back the firmware to the earlier versiob

Comment: I was having the same issue with the card on BIOS 3.08, even when the Primary Display/Video Adapter was set to PCIe.

Comment: When you said you took "it" down to the shop you mean the pc or the card?  Have you tried the card without using a DVD-D to VGA cable?

Comment: I meant the card. And I'm not sure how you can use a card without a video cable unless you mean using onboard graphics instead when the card was plugged in. In that case, there was no video signal from there either.

Comment: I meant use a DVI-D cable connected directly to a DVI-D port on the monitor or use a DisplayPort

Comment: I'm not sure how that will make a difference. Again, I don't even hear the startup sound, so I highly doubt that the card will work/display anything on any of the other connectors. I don't have a DVI-D or DisplayPort cable anyway (I have an HDMI cable and two TVs with HDMI ports, however).

Answer (score -1):

For those that might still be wondering about this, your video card might have power requirements beyond what the HP a1640n’s 300 watt power supply can provide.

Comment: My Radeon HD 3650 didn't work with it, but a GeForce 8800 GTX, which is what the PC's running now, did. I took both the card and PC down to a repair shop shortly after posting my question, and they told me that my mobo only works with PCIe 1.x GPUs, not 2.x. However, I recently tried my RX 5700 XT on it, and shockingly, it worked. My guess is that my mobo doesn't like cards powered entirely through the PCIe slot alone, like the 3650 (no 6- or 8-pin power connectors on the card). I have an MSI Radeon HD 7870 (2x 6-pin power connectors) coming in hopefully today, so hopefully that'll work.

Comment: Oh, and I also replaced my stock 300 W power supply with an EVGA 600 W 80+ White unit, so I should be good for power requirements, at least for this card. I don't plan on using anything super-high end (at least by 2020 standards) with this PC anyway.